# is Cookies and Code cache is linked in Chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, caching, cookies, browser

i have a question that if user session related data is stored in cookies and once cookies is deleted it is taking user to login page so my question is 
"**Is there any link between code downloaded so far to the user into browser and visible in source** " will it be also gets disconnected and once user deletes cookie,

if user creates new cookie for the user with successful login and then is the Browser is going to get Fresh copy of code to Source there by deleting existing cache or will use the existing code which is downloaded earlier

please help me finding answer to how Cache of code (Written in AngularJS) in browser will connect and disconnect from server based on user cookies?

i wanted to understand this

Answer (score 1):

There is no "Code cache", there is just browser cache - all *.js, *.html, images, etc. are cached by browser basing on user browser settings and http reponse headers.

This is not related to Cookies - user can leave one and delete another and vice versa. E.g. user can use site without cookies at all OR turn off browser cache, so it will load all assets each time.